# Is $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

Check whether the function $$w=\frac{1}{z}$$ is conformal or not, ans discuss how it transforms the points interior and exterior of a unit circle about the origin.

For the answer to the first part, will it be enough if I show w=f(z) is analytic, so it produces the conformal mapping. For the second part, I am lost actually.

Comment: Since $f'(z)=-1/z^2\neq 0$, the mapping is locally biholomorphic at each (nonzero) point.

Answer (score 1):

For part II of your question: Convert everything to polar. Consider $z=r \exp(i \theta)$. Then $w=\frac{1}{r} \exp(-i \theta)$. When r=1 (a point on the unit circle), the mapping gives you another point on the unit circle which is conjugate to your original point (reflected in the real-axis).

What about points inside the circle? If $r<1$, then clearly $\frac{1}{r}$ lies outside the circle. The point $r=0$ is mapped to complex infinity. Using the same argument, points exterior to the unit circle are mapped to the interior because if $r>1$, $\frac{1}{r} < 1$. So this mapping achieves inversion in the unit circle. In each case, the principal argument changes sign because you go from $+i\theta$ to $-i\theta$.

ETA: In cartesian, $w=\dfrac{1}{x+iy}$. Multiply above and below by $x-iy$ and you have
$$
w=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} - i \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}
$$
Points on the unit circle have $x^2+y^2=1$, so then
$$
w = x - i y = \bar{z}
$$
etc.

Comment: Can I also solve it by using z=x+iy and not by using polar form ?

Comment: @RoshanShrestha You can, but it is not so obvious. Let me add that.

Comment: Thanks @user_of_math Can you plot the figures for me so that I can visualize the change in the principal argument.